# How to get 16 byte aligned address in assembly

Tags: assembly, stack, memory-address, memory-alignment, fpu

I have to save floating-point registers into the stack.
I tried to use fsave instruction.
I do the following:

```
fsave (%esp)
```

But as an argument fsave uses 16 byte aligned address.

I don't have an idea how to make address in %esp be 16 byte aligned.

Comment: And address with the low 4 bits cleared is aligned on 16 bytes.

Comment: new=(old+0xF)&(~0xF);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using intel style syntax:

```
    push    ebp             ;save ebp
    mov     ebp,esp         ;save esp in ebp
    and     esp,0fffffff0h  ;round esp down to 16 byte boundary
    sub     esp,128         ;allocate multiple of 16 bytes
```

Comment: This is semi-useful advice; if you're executing an `fsave (%esp)` _after the above_, you will overwrite existing stack. While you need to align the stackpointer, don't forget you _also must allocate_ stack here ...

Comment: updated the code example. my old documentation notes that fsave can save up to 108 bytes, it might be bigger now.